# Ubuntu monitor black after login

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I am trying to update my Nvidia drive.

I installed cuda-10.2 and then I want to update my Nvidia-drive to nvidia-440.33, but an error occurs, then I followed the instruction from [unload nvidia-drm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440840/how-to-unload-kernel-module-nvidia-drm).
However, when I type the following command directly in the terminal, my screen turns black.

```
systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

Now, I don't know how to recover my computer. I tried to enter the text-only mode by trying ctrl-alt-f1~f8, these command doesn't work, I don't know if it because I press them in a wrong time.

I use dual systems, so each time I reboot, I will directly enter the screen where I choose which system I need to enter.

My system is Ubuntu 18.04, GPU Nvidia 1080Ti.

Could anyone tell me how to enter the text-only mode, so I can install the nvidia drive? or Is there any solution to recover my screen.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **recover** mode.

Select **resume**, press enter.

Select **root**, press enter.

Type command

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

**control-d** exit

Then select **resume**, press enter.

Maybe this process solved my problem.

Or

After login, if the monitor turns black,
try the magic key combination, press them in order:

R-1s, E-30s, I-10s, S-5s, U-5s, B

This also probably can solve the problem once.